# Why is my game_loop not defined even though it is?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a start screen button where the game_loop starts when you press play, but it says game_loop is not defined, even though I thought I did. I can't seem to figure out the issue, so does anyone know how to fix this? It would help a lot! :)

```
def button(x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    # print(mouse)

    if x + width > mouse[0] > x and y + height > mouse[1] > y:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, width, height), 0)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and action is not None:
                if action == 'play':
                    game_loop()
                elif action == 'quit':
                    pygame.quit()
                    quit()
    else:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, width, height), 0)

def start_screen():

    start = True

    while start:
        clock.tick(FPS)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                start = False

        screen.blit(background, background_rect)

        button(180, 285, 120, 60, BLUE, LIGHT_BLUE, 'play')
        button(202, HEIGHT - 150, 80, 40, WHITE, GRAY, 'quit')
        button(310, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY)
        button(20, 45, 140, 30, WHITE, GRAY)

        draw_text(screen, "Shoot 'Em Up", 80, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 4, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Instructions", 30, 90, 53, BLACK)
        draw_text(screen, "Credits", 35, 378, 50, BLACK)
        draw_text(screen, "Play", 55, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2, WHITE)
        draw_text(screen, "Quit", 30, WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT - 137, BLUE)

        pygame.display.flip()

start_screen()
running = True

def game_loop():
    while running:
        *game_loop code*
game_loop()
```

Comment: Please use space instead of tab to align your code. Try again.

Comment: I fixed it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

> Format your code correctly and it should work.

```
 def button(x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):

     mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
     # print(mouse)

     if x + width > mouse[0] > x and y + height > mouse[1] > y:
         pygame.draw.rect(screen, ac, (x, y, width, height), 0)
         for event in pygame.event.get():
             if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and action is not None:
                 if action == "play":
                     game_loop()
                 elif action == "quit":
                     pygame.quit()
                     quit()
     else:
         pygame.draw.rect(screen, ic, (x, y, width, height), 0)

 def game_loop():
     print('game loop') 
 game_loop()
```

Comment: Sorry, I messed up posting the code. That is how I did it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced body of `button()` with `pass`. It worked.

```
def button(x, y, width, height, ic, ac, action=None):
    pass


def game_loop():
    print('game loop') 

game_loop()
```

You should really replace tabs with spaces in your code. Alternatively copy and paste from SO to your environment.

Comment: Why would you pass that function?

Comment: I do not have pygame library. The `button` function requires a function body. So I put in `pass` to replace function body.